# GTF file format causing GeneMark-ES error

Tags: gtf

I am predicting genes using `GeneMark-ES`, I managed to generate a `gtf` file, but when I tried to extract the nt/protein sequence using `get_sequence_from_GTF.pl`, I am running into an error in the format of the gtf file, which I find puzzing as it was the gtf file was generated using `gmes_petap.pl` (an script in the `GeneMark-ES` package).

Here is the command I used and the error message which also prints the first line of the genemark.gtf file:

```
$ get_sequence_from_GTF.pl genemark.gtf DT_CAJQTU010000037_1.fasta

error in file format GTF: CAJQTU010000037.1 Desoria tigrina genome assembly, contig: utg000040l, whole genome shotgun sequence     GeneMark.hmm3   gene    2099    4039    .       +       .       gene_id "1_g"; transcript_id "1_t";
```

I think I have found the line in `get_sequence_from_GTF.pl` that is causing the error, but not being a perl monk, I am having troubles to read figure out what is wrong with my `gtf` file and more importantly figure out how to fix it.

```
...
if ( /^(\S+)\t\S+\t(\S+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t.\t([\+-])\t([012.])\tgene_id \"(\S+)\"/ )
    {
    ... (some stuff)
    }
else
{
  if ( /^\s+$/ ) { next };
  if ( /^#/ ) { next };
  die( "error in file format GTF: $_\n" );
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is a clear bug in the tool you are using. The regular expression requires that all fields in the GTF file contain no whitespace. The `\S+` means "one or more non-whitespace characters" but your "source" field, the second field in the GTF file, contains spaces: `Desoria tigrina genome assembly, contig: utg000040l, whole genome shotgun sequence`.

The thing is, that is a perfectly valid field for a GTF file! GTF fields can contain spaces, they just can't contain tabs. I tried to find a repository for the software to suggest a fix, but found only [an empty one](https://github.com/gatech-genemark/GeneMark-ES). In any case, try changing the regex you show to this:

```perl
#if ( /^(\S+)\t\S+\t(\S+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t.\t([\+-])\t([012.])\tgene_id \"(\S+)\"/ )
if ( /^([^\t]+)\t[^\t]+\t([^\t]+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t.\t([\+-])\t([012.])\tgene_id \"(\S+)\"/ )
    {
    ... (some stuff)
    }
```

I can't guarantee that this will work as expected, please test! The details will depend on what they do with the captured groups (the `some stuff`), but at least that regex will match and I *think* I have kept the numbering of the capture groups.

Comment: I agree with this 100%. I read the regex and didn't spot the reply. There are quite a few problems, the use of a bare "." just means 'any character' rather '\.' which in this example would fit (albeit it might be intentional). The final section '; transcript_id "1_t";' isn't captured. However, the key problem is `\S` which will trip over the space characters in "CAJQTU010000037.1 Desoria tigrina genome assembly, contig: utg000040l, whole genome shotgun sequence". The use of '[^\t]', i.e. not a tab character will work. Personally I would split on the tab character.

Comment: Just to clarify this "\t.\t" means any single character between two tabs. However, this "[012.]" might mean a `\.` i.e. just a full-stop, I can't remember. If it doesn't `[.]` is exactly the same as `[012.]` or even `[a-z|0-9]` and beyond. Anyway this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `agat_sp_extract_sequences.pl` from [AGAT](https://github.com/NBISweden/AGAT) instead.

To extract and translate the coding regions:
`agat_sp_extract_sequences.pl -g infile.gxf -f infile.fasta -p`

see here for all possibilities with that script: https://agat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/agat_sp_extract_sequences.html

Otherwise with the modification suggested by @terdon, your script should work fine.